# How can I scan (unicast scanning) only one specific AP instead of scanning channels?

Tags: android, wifi, network-scan

Is it possible to scan only a specific AP (unicast scanning) and display its Round-trip-time in android? (such as an AP deployed in IEEE 802.11b Channel 1). What i want to see is whether the scanning time intervals of my AP are different in case the AP is empty or highly loaded.

In order to scan all channels, I use the `mainWifiObj2.startScan()` function. This function returns the following list

```
List<ScanResult> wifiScanList1 = mainWifiObj1.getScanResults();
```

This list displays related information in all channels, such as SSIDs, MAC adresses, signal levels, and timestamps of all scanned channels, as is shown in [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6DhzzYgg24tRWZuMU5yM2YwNGM/edit?usp=docslist_api).

First of all, do u know what the timestamp (shown in the linked image) means? I have launched my application both when the AP is empty and higly loaded with laptops (uploading/downloading files). However, the timestamp values of the channel, which my AP is connected, were too close to eachother in both scenarios.

In short, how can I scan (unicast scanning) only one specific AP instead of scanning channels?

Do you think it is because of MaxChTime durations? 
If so, How can I reduce the MaxChTime?

Answer (score 1):

"First of all, do u know what the timestamp (shown in the linked image) means?"

That's the TSF value.

See this:
https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/8203/mac-timestamp-measurement-unit

Comment: How is TSF value transferred in real time ? but my real problem is scan (unicast scanning) only one specific AP instead of scanning channels ?